# Failed to generate apk for my project in android studio

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, apk, android-studio-3.0

I am working on existing project of android app with java, i imported the project successfully and synced it with gradle successfully but getting to build apk I cale across this problem

> {Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @6edd9065}

I have tried many things but still getting same error message

Comment: update gradle version and may be some dependency not work properly so update project because i facing same issue i update project it works me.

Comment: Old projects need old Java/JDK versions (8 or 11). Make sure `JAVA_HOME` points to an JDK8 or in Android Studio JDK 8 is selected to be used with Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a JDK compatibility issue. Try using a different version of JDK, like [11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html). You will probably have to specify the path to the jdk in local.properties.
Also, have a look at this
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/287#issuecomment-893476072